# Docker-Compose: is it possible to force IP addresses on different containers?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I was reading through these docs, https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

```
version: '2'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

Through this, I know that I could access the IP Address where web is located via something like `myapp_web`, depending on how I configure it, but is it possible to do something like:

```
version: '2'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    ip: 172.0.0.4
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

Which would force web to be located at the IP address 172.0.0.4? I haven't found anything in the docs about this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want static ip address you need create user-defined network.
And use any address you want.